# FullCalendar: Display events in a listview only for the current view

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using FullCalendar v4 and trying to display all the events which are available only for the current view in a custom list view.

Current view in the sense, let's say if I'm in 'dayGridMonth' view, I need get the events for the entire month which is currently on. Likewise if I'm in 'timeGridWeek' view, I need to get the events for the entire week which is currently active.

I'm using FullCalendar Angular plugin and I have tried the following code using `getEvents()` method.

```
let CalendarApi = this.calendar.getApi();
let events = CalendarApi.getEvents()

console.log(events);
```

Using this way, FullCalendar displays all the events no matter what view I'm in. I want something like a lazy loading way where the events are loaded only for the current view (time period).

Comment: Do you want a list of events in current view or do you only want to fetch the events in the view time span? eventRender(event) will only render events in view, so maybe do something with that.

Comment: This is the only way to get events. If you want a narrower set of events, you'll need to filter them yourself after you've got them out of fullCalendar. fullCalendar can tell you the start/end dates of the current view, and you can use those to filter your list. Or maybe actually your server can already tell you more easily, with a quick AJAX request? I don't know, depends how you've structured your application.

Comment: @Layera I want to fetch the events in the view time span.

Comment: @Layera eventRender method worked for me. Could you please post your comment as an answer? I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
eventRender(event){}
```

It will render events in current view

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some steps:

1) Identify the change of view (click at button 'month' or 'week' for example).

2) On change of view, you erase ou insert the list of events you want for that view.

How to do these steps on code:

1)
At the component, put a callback that return the view:

```
<full-calendar (viewSkeletonRender)="handleViewRender($event)"></full-calendar>
```

At your code, create the method 'handleViewRender':

```
handleViewRender($event) {
   if ($event.view.viewSpec.buttonTextDefault === 'month') {
       // step 2 here, change the list of events for month view
   } else if ($event.view.viewSpec.buttonTextDefault === 'week') {
       // step 2 here, change the list of events for week view
   }

   alert($event.view.viewSpec.buttonTextDefault );
}
```

I think you already know how to put a list of events at the calendar, and if not, is so simple to find... so i will not put the code here.

Official doc about events on calendar, most of code is in jQuery:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Official doc about viewSkeletonRender, this doc is so poor.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewSkeletonRender

I hope it helps.